# Can the <link> tag be used to prefetch audio files?

Tags: html, prefetch

I can across `rel="prefetch"` attribute of `<link>` tag. On [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ), they just showed prefetching CSS files.

More specifically:

> Link prefetching is a browser mechanism, which utilizes browser idle
> time to download or prefetch **documents**

Besides prefetching **documents**, can it be used to prefetch audio files too?

Comment: Audio files are documents.

Comment: @melpomenes how come? I always thought of documents as files that are editable and deal with text

Comment: @EdwardTorvalds Document and file are interchangeable terms for the same kind of object, when it comes to web technologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It guess it works for anything, audio, video, images and so on:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="foo.mp3">
```

and inside your body just put

```
<a href="foo.mp3">foo.mp3</a>
```

It's cached now...

https://css-tricks.com/prefetching-preloading-prebrowsing/

Answer (score 2):

To prefetch properly use the following in the head of the document.

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="foo.mp3" as="audio">
```